Old japanese sci-fi about heros who crash lands alien ship on duplicate earth
Japanese sci-fi from 1970-1990. An alien is trying to reach earth but a group of heroes created or duplicated a fake earth to crash land into. The alien had a flat or disc like head. He had more than one form and had too be killed numerous times. I remember seeing it on VHS, way back in the 90's. At the very last scene all or the heroes huddled together and a snap shot is taken of them.

Animated or live action?

Zeiram, (1991), had a sort of disk-shaped head:

Much of the action take place in an artificial dimension called "The Zone", which could be considered an artificial earth.  From Dr. Hermes:

Before the battles get started, Iria transports Zeiram to an alternate
  dimension known as the Zone. As far as I can tell, this is mainly a
  way for the filmmakers to use empty industrial sites without a lot of
  people getting in the way, but it does also give the movie a
  ticking-clock effect as the Zone only lasts for a limited time and she
  has to get done and get out before disintegrating.

The movie also ends with a snapshot being taken:

The film's closing image as Bob takes a snapshot of Iria smiling with
  her two new friends is charming because, not long earlier, she had no
  use for them and wanted to "dispose" of the nuisances.

